# AVAudioPlayer - Why is there a gap between loops (uncompressed audio)

Tags: ios, iphone, loops, audio

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"caf"];
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
[audioPlayer setNumberOfLoops:-1];
[audioPlayer setVolume: 0.1];
[audioPlayer play];
```

This is the basic code I've got, let me know if you need to know more.

tried both compressed and uncompressed formats both have a gap of about ~1 second when running on iPhone simulator (don't have dev license to run on device to test).

Am i missing something, I've been searching posts but i can only see issues with compressed audio (which makes sense).

**Xcode:** Version 6.2 (6C131e)

**OS:** OS X Yosemite Version 10.10.2 (14C1510)

**Hardware:** Macbook Air 13" (Early 2014) - 4GB

Comment: It could be because of the time the player needs to seek back to the beginning.. Also check if your audio is silent in the beginning and/or end that could also give a feel that there is a gap..

Comment: ~4 seconds long, 791kb file, no compression & no silence in file. also a 14mb file compressed 5min 46sec file has about the same gap as the 4 second < 1mb uncompressed file with each loop. Playback is normal just the loop gap is the issue. 

@uchiha thanks for your comment, if its a delay in seeking to the beginning how do sleep aid apps work (rain noise etc). I'm assuming they don't have 10hr files etc :P

Answer (score 1):

have you try a "prepareToPlay" before playing like this :

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"caf"];
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL  fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
[audioPlayer setNumberOfLoops:-1];
[audioPlayer setVolume: 0.1];
[audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
[audioPlayer play];
```

Comment: I am facing the same problem. I had tried "prepareToPlay". But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I solve it using [AVQueuePlayer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avqueueplayer), Create one **AVQueuePlayer** player and try to buffer (enqueue) two or three **AVPlayerItem** with mp3 media files in advance in a lazy mode via **AVPlayerActionAtItemEnd**